# Calculate the difference in years in a long data.table format

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose we have the following data set:

```
library(data.table)

t <- data.table(id = c(1,3,1,3,4,1,3, 4),
                year = c(2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019),
                value = c(1,1,3,2,4,5,6, 9))
```

I would like to calculate (without transforming it into a wide data set) the difference between every year in a column. It can be safely assumed that every year is present, but not every id is present in every year.

The result should look like a column of:
NA, NA, 2, 1, NA, 2, 4, 5

(the value in the current year minus the value in the previous year)

How would I go around to perform this calculation, as it seems that the standard assignment of variables in data.table does not allow for it?

```
t[, diff := ???]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shift` function from a `data.table` package.

```
# Should work with given OP's data (t)
data[, difference := value - shift(value), id]
```

PS:

- Don't use `t` as an object (it's a base R function)
- Don't use `diff` as a column name  (it's a base R function)

Answer (score 0):

Or use `diff` to take the difference of adjacent elements by 'id'

```
t[,  difference := c(NA, diff(value)), id]
```